# Get the billing address associated to PayPal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway

I added PayPal button to React and I want to be able to get the billing address from PayPal

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    window.paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            intent: 'CAPTURE',
            purchase_units: [
              {
                amount: {
                  currency_code: 'GBP',
                  value: Math.ceil(total * 0.72411175 * 100) / 100,
                },
              },
            ],
          })
        },
        onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
          const order = await actions.order.capture()
          //console.log(order)
        },
        onError: (err) => {
          console.log(err)
        },
      })
      .render(paypal.current)
  }, []) // eslint-disable-line
```

but this only returns an object with the ID, Name and Email, and I want to be able to get the address, phone number and postal code.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There will be a *shipping* address in the response. Blow it up to formatted JSON with:

```
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                console.log(details);
                console.log(JSON.stringify( JSON.parse(details) ,null,2) );
                //This is where you should show a success message or redirect.
                //If you need to anything that touches a server database, use a server-side create and capture instead of the client-side actions.order.create() / .capture()
            });
        }
```

Billing information is kept private at PayPal by design, not shared.

Comment: this is worked but for some reason i can't store this data to my database

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong, but as the comment there states you should not be attempting to store this data to a database. These are client side calls. If you need to do a database write, the call to create and capture should originate from your server. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls